# Fill in missing dates for multiple values with a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to write a single query for retrieving time information for multiple users over a date range.

My tables are set up as follows:

Entry:

```
user_id  | entry_date  | entry_hours
1        | 2013-11-12  | 4
1        | 2013-11-12  | 5
1        | 2013-11-13  | 3
2        | 2013-11-13  | 7
....
```

Calendar:

```
calendar_date
.....
2013-11-10
2013-11-11
2013-11-12
2013-11-13
2013-11-14
.....
```

If I run this query:

```
SELECT *, e.user_id, e.entry_date, COALESCE(SUM(e.entry_hours), 0) as total
            FROM `entry` e
            WHERE entry_date BETWEEN '2013-11-12' and '2013-11-13'
            GROUP BY e.user_id, e.entry_date
```

I get something to the effect of

```
user_id  |  entry_date  |  total
  1      |  2013-11-12  |  9
  1      |  2013-11-13  |  3
  2      |  2013-11-13  |  7
```

When I would like this instead:

```
user_id  |  entry_date  |  total
  1      |  2013-11-12  |  9
  1      |  2013-11-13  |  3
  2      |  2013-11-12  |  0
  2      |  2013-11-13  |  7
```

Where it fills in the missing date with a 0.

EDIT: I would also need it to pull in user_id's with 0's when they have no listed entries. Say I included in there `WHERE` clause `AND user_id IN (1,2,3)`, I would get something like:

```
user_id  |  entry_date  |  total
  1      |  2013-11-12  |  9
  1      |  2013-11-13  |  3
  2      |  2013-11-12  |  0
  2      |  2013-11-13  |  7
  3      |  2013-11-12  |  0
  3      |  2013-11-13  |  0
```

The idea behind the calendar table was to be able to pull all dates in a range and join them with the entry table to fill in those missing dates, but I've been unable to figure out how to do this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  u.user_id,
  c.calendar_date,
  COALESCE(SUM(e.entry_hours), 0)
FROM calendar c
CROSS JOIN users u
LEFT JOIN entry e
   ON (c.calendar_date = e.entry_date AND u.user_id = e.user_id)
GROUP BY u.user_id,c.calendar_date
```

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something in the original post -- see my edit. I also need it to fill in with 0's where the user_id is supplied in the where clause, but there are no entries in the table for that user.

Comment: You'll need a separate table that lists your users, just like the calendar

Comment: I do have a user table that contains the user_id -- would I need to join on that as well?

Comment: Yes.  Everything in your result has to come from somewhere.  If you want user_ids that are missing from the entries table, you need to bring in a table that has them.